# Updating mongo document after it's been found

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I'm trying to update a number of documents from an array of object ids passed. I want to be able to update each document by pushing the userid into the visitor array. 
  i'm getting this error CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value. see my code below

```
var estates = req.params.estates.split(',');
 Estate.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: { $in: estates } }).then(function(Estate)
{
   Estate.visitors.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId( req.params.userid));
   Estate.save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [mongoose documentations](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) `findByIdAndUpdate` first param is an `id` which you are passing an `object`

try replacing it by `findOne({ _id: { $in: estates } })`

Comment: This worked great, thank you for your help. I ended up using this in conjunction with map to loop array past to find and update each document.

Answer (score 0):

Your API usage is wrong, first argument for `findByIdAndUpdate` should be an `id`, it fails to cast array to id.

for matching and updating multiple documents,

you need to use `updateMany`

```
db.foo.updateMany({"_id" : { $in : [1,2,3] }},{$push : {test: 2}},{$upsert : false})
```

or `update` with `multi : true` option

```
db.store.update({"_id" : { $in : [1,2,3] }},{$push : {test: 2}},{$upsert : false, multi : true})
```

output

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

Mongoose

```
Estate.update({ _id: { $in: estates } }, {$push : {visitors : req.params.userid}}, {multi : true, upsert : false})
```

[Doc findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)